# How to know if Bitlocker is installed from python?

Tags: python, windows

I need to know if Bitlocker is installed on windows. I tried executing "C:\Windows\system32\manage-bde.exe -status" from cmd and it works, but from python using subprocess library don't works it got to me this error:
"C:\Windows\system32\manage-bde.exe" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo"

Code:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
p = Popen(['C:\\Windows\\system32\\manage-bde.exe', '-status'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, shell=True)
lines = p.stdout.readlines()
for line in lines:
    print line
```

Comment: Please post the error in English.

Comment: You're using 32-bit Python, so accessing `System32` gets redirected to `SysWOW64`. Use the virtual `Sysnative` directory to access the real 64-bit `System32` directory. For example: `system_root = os.environ.get('SystemRoot', 'C:\\Windows');` `system32 = 'Sysnative' if (platform.architecture()[0] == '32bit' and platform.machine() == 'AMD64') else 'System32';` `manage_bde = os.path.join(system_root, system32, 'manage-bde.exe')`.

Comment: By the way, don't use `shell=True` for this. Run the command directly. Only invoke the shell when using its built-in commands makes a task easier, which is rare on Windows considering the default `%ComSpec%` shell is cmd.exe.